# Extract ID and distinct errors between two rows containing same id

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark dataframe that has two columns ("time_stamp" and "message").

Example dataframe:

```
Time_stamp                   Message
2020-12-01 05:28:34:215      some text1 ID: 1
2020-12-01 05:28:40:210      some text2 error: A
2020-12-01 05:28:40:220      some text3 error: B
2020-12-01 05:28:41:203      some text4 error: A
2020-12-01 05:30:43:201      some text5 ID: 1
2020-12-01 05:32:50:215      some text6 ID: 2
2020-12-01 05:32:50:220      some text7 error: A
2020-12-01 05:48:51:220      some text8 error: C
2020-12-01 05:48:52:203      some text9 error: B
2020-12-01 05:51:53:201      some text10 ID: 2
```

I want to make another dataframe with ID and distinct errors between two rows containing same id.

Expected output:

Example table:

```
ID          Error
1           A
1           B
2           A
2           C
2           B
```

I tried the following code. However, it uses windows function which is not supported by Azure Databricks and the code takes ages to execute.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'Time_stamp',
    F.to_timestamp('Time_stamp', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS')
).withColumn(
    'ID',
    F.regexp_extract('Message', 'ID: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 1)
).withColumn(
    'ID',
    F.last(F.when(F.col('ID') != '', F.col('ID')), True).over(Window.orderBy('Time_stamp'))
).filter(
    F.col('message').rlike('error')
).withColumn(
    'Message',
    F.regexp_extract('Message', 'error: (.*)', 1)
).groupBy('ID').agg(
    F.collect_set(F.array('Message', 'Time_stamp')).alias('Message')
).select(
    'ID',
    F.explode('Message').alias('Message')
).selectExpr(
    'ID',
    'Message[0] as error',
    'Message[1] as Time_stamp'
).withColumn(
    'rn',
    F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('ID', 'error').orderBy('Time_stamp'))
).filter('rn = 1').orderBy('Time_stamp').select('ID', 'error')
```

Can anyone provide a solution with SQL? PySpark SQL is well supported in Azure databricks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to say, except that I think pyspark looks nicer than spark SQL...

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView('df')

result = spark.sql("""
select ID, error
from (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by ID, error order by Time_stamp) rn
  from (
    select ID, Message[0] error, Message[1] Time_stamp
    from (
      select ID, explode(Message) Message
      from (
        select ID, collect_set(array(Message, Time_stamp)) Message
        from (
          select Time_stamp, regexp_extract(Message, 'error: (.*)', 1) Message, ID 
          from (
            select Time_stamp, Message, last(case when ID != '' then ID end, true) over (order by Time_stamp) ID
            from (
              select to_timestamp(Time_stamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS') Time_stamp, Message, regexp_extract(Message, 'ID: ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)', 1) ID
              from df
            )
          ) where Message rlike 'error'
        ) group by ID
      )
    )
  )
) where rn = 1 order by Time_stamp""")

result.show()
+---+-----+
| ID|error|
+---+-----+
|  1|    A|
|  1|    B|
|  2|    A|
|  2|    C|
|  2|    B|
+---+-----+
```